# Can't delete Alex voice from the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode-simulator, accessibility, voiceover

I'm working with iOS voices for accessibility reasons. In iOS simulator I've tried to install Alex voice which is one of the most popular English voices. To choose it I downloaded it first. However, after that, the voice looks like something between enabled and disabled.

E.g. for Allison I see that it's not downloaded hence it's not available for me. On the other hand, Samantha is downloaded, so I can navigate further and edit the voice, for example I can delete it. But for Alex I can't neither delete it nor select it to use later.

When I try to press `Erase All Content and Settings...` for the simulator, sometimes it doesn't change anything, but sometimes it erases Alex voice, but situation returns after downloading this voice. Is there any other way how it Alex can be installed on the simulator?

[image]

Comment: This appears to be an old bug. I found one article on Google that suggests there might be a long standing bug with the Alex voice https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6585481?page=1, it has a couple of suggestions in there you could try (although it may be difficult with an emulator)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this bug is a factory reset, which erases everything

Comment: Where exactly did you get this idea? And does the iOS simulator has factory reset? I haven't seen it before